# Chooser created with createChooser(intent title) doesn't display a title

Tags: android

I am getting my hands on implementing a file chooser. The `createChooser` method takes a `CharSequence title`, but it doesn't actually display this title in any resulting chooser (tested on multiple API levels).

```
private void openFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}
```

Where is this title supposed to be displayed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Intent.createChooser()` is a convenience wrapper around crafting an `ACTION_CHOOSER` `Intent`, where the supplied title is provided via `EXTRA_TITLE`.

> Where is this title supposed to be displayed?

The `ACTION_CHOOSER` implementation ideally would display the title as part of its UI. However:

- There is no requirement that the `ACTION_CHOOSER` activity display the title
- The implementation of the `ACTION_CHOOSER` activity can vary by device manufacturer as well as OS version
- You will not always get a chooser (e.g., there are 0-1 activities that match your `Intent`)

In the particular case of `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, that will tend to route directly to a system-supplied UI for obtaining content, bypassing any chooser, on Android 4.4+.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Please allow me one more question that is connected with this: Does `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` with `setType("image/*)` not need a permission to read external storage? Because on my emulator I can access what I think is the external storage without ever granting this permission. I cant find anything in google

Comment: @FlorianWalther: "Does ACTION_GET_CONTENT with setType("image/*) not need a permission to read external storage?" -- correct. On Android 4.3 and older, you do not need a permission to *read* external storage in general. On Android 4.4+, `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` should return a `Uri` with a `content` scheme, not a `file` scheme, and you have temporary rights to access the content identified by that `Uri`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is how I somewhat understood it, but I didn't find anything specific in Google. However, you said that 4.3+ doesn't need a read external storage permission in general, but I found so many examples about requesting runtime permission for exactly that: READ external storage. Do I understand something wrong?

Comment: @FlorianWalther: No, I said that Android 4.3 *and older* do not need a permission to read external storage. You need a permission to read external storage on Android 4.4+. Using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, you are not reading external storage -- a `ContentProvider` supplied by the system is.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. Makes total sense now! Amazing, that was really really helpful. Happy new year!

Comment: Sorry, one more thing: My min API level is 19 and its bypassing the chooser. Should I therefore use another method or is it better to still implement this createChooser method? I have no experience with that and I now want to decide if I should just pass the intent, or intent.createChooser

Comment: @FlorianWalther: "Should I therefore use another method or is it better to still implement this createChooser method?" -- just skip the `createChooser()`. You rarely want to force a chooser anyway. That's mostly for `ACTION_SEND`.

Comment: So I just pass the intent. Will that ever lead to any incompatibilities? It gets handled like this in a lot of tutorials, but I guess there is a lot of copy pasting going on.

Comment: @FlorianWalther: "Will that ever lead to any incompatibilities?" -- I do not know what sort of incompatibilities you are concerned about here, and "ever" is a very long time. :-)

Comment: Ok I understand. Thanks a lot for your help!